# MATLAB API for C exception using matGetDir: matrix::serialize::EndOfFile at memory location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, matlab

I try to read a mat file in a c++ Visual Studio 2017 project on Windows 7. I use the MATLAB API for C from Matlab R2017b.

I am able to run the matdgns.c example in Matlab using mex.

It's also possible to run the application in my c++ project and open the mat file using

```
pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
```

However, when I try to read the array list using `matGetDir`

```
dir = (const char **)matGetDir(pmat, &ndir);
```

I get an exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x000007FEFCF4A06D in project_gTest.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: matrix::serialize::EndOfFile at memory
>   location 0x000000000031F1D0.

How can I solve this issue? Am I missing another library?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the following answer from Matlab support which "solves" the "issue":

I assume that this Exception which you "get" is basically just a line of text shown in the "Output" Window of Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, right? And this is not actually crashing your application, correct?

If that is indeed the case, please note that MSVS 2017 does in fact show *first chance exceptions* in "Output". If such an exception is caught and handled, where in this particular case I do expect that the MATLAB libraries handled this, there is no actual issue though. It is perfectly valid to throw exceptions and then handle them. Only unhandled (second chance) exceptions would lead to real problems.

It should normally be perfectly safe to ignore that line which is shown in the Output and it is in fact expected that this Exception is thrown (and caught internally) when working with matGetDir.